# Why is it said that, because gravity can bend light, that this entails a curvature of space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

Why can't gravity affect light directly without any reference to space-time?

How does light bending show that space-time is curved?

I would have thought that it shows that massless particles are subject to classical gravity just like massive particles.
The curvature or lack of curvature of space-time seems irrelevant and unnecessary to an understanding of gravity.

What have I missed?

Comment: There is nice explanation in Gravitation by Misner, Wheeler, Thorne, chapter 7.3 "Gravitational redshift implies spacetime is curved"

Comment: If you do not have the book, it is partially described here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413910/doubt-schilds-argument-about-spacetime-curvature

Comment: The general theory of relativity has been consistent with all experimental observations. This indirectly implies that the idea of light bending should be correctly described by curvature of space-time. It is due to the agreement with observations that we have accepted this picture

Comment: Photon trajectories can be altered by gravity directly proportional to their proximity to the mass they are passing.

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't gravity affect light directly without any reference to space-time? How does light bending show that space-time is curved?

This is a good question, and like many good questions the answer is not straightforward.

First, strictly speaking, the observation of light bending does not support spacetime curvature per se, what it supports is specifically the theory of general relativity (GR) which is most commonly expressed in terms of curved spacetime. It turns out that Newtonian gravity can also be expressed in terms of curved spacetime. This is called Newton Cartan gravity, which uses curved spacetime but is experimentally identical to Newtonian gravity.

Secondly, it is not exactly clear how to treat light under Newtonian gravity. With the Newton Cartan formulation you would get a bending of light rays, but the value of the bend would be 1/2 the value of the bend predicted by GR. With the regular formulation of Newtonian gravity, if you treated light as a massless particle then since the acceleration is independent of the mass you would get a gravitational deflection. Again, the amount of deflection is half the GR prediction. Finally, if you use the standard Newtonian formulation and Maxwell’s equations in a Newtonian inertial frame then you would get no gravitational deflection.

Now, the observed bending matches the GR prediction and excludes either the 0 bending or 1/2 bending predicted by Newtonian physics. So the observation supports GR over either the standard formulation of Newtonian gravity without spacetime curvature or even the Newton Cartan formulation that does use curved spacetime.

Overall, I would say that the observed bending supports GR, not specifically spacetime curvature. With the understanding that spacetime curvature is a big part of GR.

Answer (score 2):

General relativity has not been created to explain the bending of light, which was observed years afterwards only.

And indeed, the idea of gravity having an effect on light was not absent from Newtonian mechanics (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens#History).

So it definitely cannot be said that light bending entails the curvature of spacetime. It is the other way around: general relativity describes the whole of gravity via the curvature of spacetime and, in that framework, light bending becomes a (confirmed) prediction of the theory.

Answer (score 2):

In support of Dale's excellent answer I will show in the following how the deflection of light can be computed in Newton's theory.

For this purpose we consider a light ray usually moving along the x-axis passing along the sun which is located below the ray (and therefore below the x-axis). The light ray gets deviated in the direction of the y-axis according to the well-known law (may be here Special Relativity is needed to explain the attraction that is exerted on the light ray via $m =\frac{E}{c^2}$):

$$y = \frac{g}{2} t^2$$

where $g$ corresponds to the gravitational acceleration which can be quantified by $g = \frac{GM}{R^2}$ with $M$ mass of the sun,  $R$ as radius of the sun (we assume that the light ray passes really very close along the sun's surface). We can relate the time it takes with the position of the ray  along the x-axis: $x=ct$. Thus we get an relationship between the y-coordinate of the ray with its x-coordinate:

$$ y(x) =  \frac{g}{2c^2}x^2 = \frac{GM}{2R^2 c^2}x^2$$

Of course the value of the y-coordinate is very small, grosso modo the approximation that the ray moves along the x-axis is still very good what justifies $x=ct$.
In order to obtain the angle we take the derivative of the y-coordinate of the ray:

$$y'(x) = \frac{GM}{R^2c^2}x$$

So we get the deviation angle as a function of the x-coordinate of the ray. In order to get the ray's full deviation the light needs to travel
a distance along $x$  that corresponds to the diameter of the sun (the distance the light ray is under the impact of the gravitational force of the sun):

$$\delta = y'(2R) = \frac{2GM}{Rc^2} = \frac{1}{2} \delta_{GR}$$

Yes, Newton's theory indeed predicts the deviation of light, but only half the value of the deviation of General Relativity (GR). So in order to explain the measured light deviation of $\delta_{GR}=1.75''$ General Relativity --- i.e. curvature of space-time --- is needed. But it is actually only a test of the linear part of GR. By the way, even Einstein originally predicted this value 1911 (wrongly)  4 years before the full accomplishment of his theory of General Relativity.

Comment: Very nice walk through the math. +1

Comment: @Dale actually the explanation should come along with a picture, without picture I tried to be more explicit ... in case of interest I could still upload a drawing.

Comment: Well, if you have a picture handy that would be great, but if it is a lot of effort you probably needn’t bother. Answers with pictures tend to get more upvotes

Comment: @Dale may be tomorrow. Anyway, it 'd be very schematic only.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding spacetime curvature is very relevant to understanding gravity. Gravity is not a true force. One can tell this by the fact that under free fall the proper-acceleration of the body is zero. Whereas an observer standing on earth would experience a net force or will have a proper acceleration.

Light travels in a straight line when the observer is in inertial frame. But when we look from a non-inertial frame, that straight path gets curved (called a *lightlike geodesic*). This concept tells us there has to be some curvature that is responsible for gravity.

Why at all the spacetime is curved, cause we try to relate it with the curved path that light follow. This suggest that spacetime is curved rather than being flat, and it uniquely describes all the **events** (in space and time).

Gravity cannot influence light if we consider Newtonian gravity (as light has no mass). But to explain the phenomenon of light bending. Einstein devised the concept of **spacetime curvature**.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think this answer repeats confusing things about GR you hear everywhere else. Gravity is of course a force, and a true one. It is 'just' described geometrically (by the way: All the other forces are described geometrically, too, if you ask a mathematician or a mathematical physicist).

Comment: Gravity is different from other forces.

Comment: That is true... but it still is a force.

Comment: When other forces like electromagnetic, mechanical act on a body then the body definitely has proper acceleration. But in case of gravity under free fall, body's proper acceleration is zero.

Comment: That is why, gravity is treated differently than all other forces.

Comment: @Koschi  The answer states that gravity is not a "true force" in the traditional sense of force. The answer is stating that it is force that emerges from spacetime curvature. The answer does not say "gravity is not a force".

Comment: And what do you mean with 'Light travels in a straight line when the observer is in inertial frame. But when we look from a non-inertial frame, that straight path gets curved.'? Can you give an example for this? For example bending of light of a distant star around  the Sun: can you give the non-inertial frames in which the light actually follows a geodesic, and the inertial frame in which it does NOT, but follows an actual straight line (I keep in mind that people sometimes call geodesics 'straight lines' in GR, but you do not seem to do this here)

Comment: @Koschi Yes, sure

Comment: A geodesic is a curve followed by a body when its proper acceleration is zero $\displaystyle \frac {\partial^2\vec{S}}{\partial \lambda^2} \text {where} \lambda \text {is the function of time (or path function)}$. Now consider two observers: $\{ O_1\}$ one at rest with an inertial frame(will have vertical worldline in $2D$ spacetime $(ct,x)$) and $\{ O_2\}$ other with a proper acceleration of $\alpha$ (will have hyperbolic worldline in $2D$ spacetime $(ct' , x')$).

Comment: Now, assume that light has an equation $x = ct + x_0$ in the frame with wrt  $O_1$ . $O_2 $ as moves in a hyperbola (or Rindler co-ordinate system) will observe the equation of light as: $\displaystyle x' = x_0 e^{\frac {ct'}{D}}$

Comment: Where $D = \frac { c^2}{\alpha}$ is a unit Rindler distance . It is quite a log derivation, but the result tells you about the path of light observed by two observers.

Comment: Geodesic is a vast concept : It is basically the shortest path between two points in space. If the geodesic is a straight line then we can say the frame is inertial. And more to add, to find a geodesic equation one need to equate the tangential component of 4-acceleration to zero.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi This is all correct, but maybe still a little misleading, since your example works in Minkowski spacetime, a solution in which *no gravity whatsoever* is present, usually referred to as *special relativity*. Your assumption that the geodesic of light for an inertial observer is $x=ct+x_0$ is true in Minkowski space, but not in general in general relativity. Here, the geodesics can look different, even for inertial observers. This is why light can bend around the Sun: In the Schwarzschild metric there are light-like geodesics that are not straight lines for initial observers.

Comment: I am not convinced about the fact that light can follow a curve for inertial observers. I am a high school student and not into very detailing of GR but am aware about the ideas and some Tensor calculus. I would like if you give a link or some source for your statement.

Comment: @Nikola Alfredi If it is true that you are high school student, I can say that you have already developed a strong foundation of GR..and you are probably heading the right way. Koschi was trying to say that there are mathematical structures called Principal Lie group Bundles, where gravity as well as Electro magnetism and Yang Mills can be described purely using abstract geometrical construct, on the same foundation. Nevertheless gravity is different from all of them.

Comment: @KP99 Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi Knowing that much about SR in high school is impressive...! Keep up learning things about physics! So about GR: You probably know the definition of a light-like curve, and the geodesic equation. A curve must be a solution of the latter and a light-like curve to describe a light ray. The straight line solution you gave does both of this in Minkowski space, but this is not true for a general metric. For example for the Schwarzschild metric describes the surrounding of a black hole (or a star, if you're not too close)....

Comment: ...The Schwarzschild metric has non-vanishing Christoffel symbols (don't know if you heard about them) and therefore the geodesic equation is different. In the end, the differential equation a light ray has to fulfill is different and not solved by a straight line. I looked for some references and the easiest open source reference I could find is this: https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics411/html/page2/files/Lecture.30.pdf The $\rho$ coordinate is defined as $\rho=1/r$, where $r$ is the radial coordinate of the spherical Schwarzschild metric. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Koschi I know about Christoffel symbols and it's formula in both extrinsic and intrinsic geometry(Levi-civita connection), Lie brackets, Torsion and Riemannian curvature tensor, just basic information and formulae; and recently studying Stress-Momentum tensor. And thank you for the link.